# php install yaml extension

Tags: php, debian, installation, yaml

I try to install yaml extension for PHP. 
I follow this tutorial : https://github.com/LegendOfMCPE/LoM-CMS/wiki/How-to-Install-LibYAML

I have already do:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear libyaml-dev
pecl install yaml
```

But I don't understand the end:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
extension=yaml.so
```

Can you explain me the last commands?

Comment: It's not command. You have to open your php.ini file and add line `extension=yaml.so`

Comment: this question and answer still work in 2021 and php7.4 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 3):

You need to edit **php.ini** file in order to unable the extension. Here is how you can do it.

Command to open and edit the file.

```
sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Above command might ask you for the system password you're working on. I've used `nano` as a text editor you can use any of your choice. (e.g. `gedit`)

Now go to end of the opened file and paste the following code.

```
extension=yaml.so
```

Now save the opened file and close it.

---

That's all it needs to setup the library. Make sure you restart the apache server to make changes work.

You can restart apache server using following command.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: why when I execute the commande to open and edit the file I heve this error : Error opening terminal: unknown. ?

Comment: Which version of PHP you've installed on the system?

Comment: `ls /etc/php5/apache2/` try this. Do you see php.ini file listed?

Comment: Yes I have " conf.d php.ini " What is mean?

Comment: It means you've `php.ini` file on the location. Which editor do you use to edit files ?

Comment: I use Atom. I need to open this file with atom and add "extension=yaml.so"?

Comment: ok, but I have just a problem, do you know how to keep the file? Or how can I modify the file via command line? Because php.ini is on server and I don't know how keep it

Comment: If it's on server, you can connect to server from terminal and use `nano` editor to edit the file.

Comment: I write this : /var/www/html# nano /etc/php5/apache5/php.ini but I think it not the correct syntax...

Comment: Is it remote server or your local server?

Comment: it a remote server. I in a docker container

Comment: Then learn how to connect to remote server, and then edit that file.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm already connected to the server. I log with : root@90b88d7f164:/var/www/html#  ...

Answer (score -2):

You're installing a compiled PHP extension (which is what that `.so` file is). You need to tell PHP to load that file. You can do this inside php.ini or, depending on your install, you sometimes will have a directory for pre-compiled(packaged) extensions (i.e. `/etc/php.d`)

You have a typo though

```
extention=yaml.so
```